# -webkit-pictograph not working on safari

Tags: css

I employed font  `-webkit-pictograph;`
It displays good on chrome and opera browser,

[image]

but as for safari,

[image]

It return little helpful info when search -webkit-pictograph safari.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to clean cache in browser.
2. If you open the dev console and see what files the browser is pulling from your site, you'll be able to see if it's downloading the font file in Safari.